# R: convert list names to matrix entries

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list object that looks like this:

```
str(regul))
List of 656
 $ 10001    :List of 2
  ..$ tfmode    : Named num [1:168] 0.994 0.992 -0.743 0.906 0.683 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:168] "22938" "5684" "9780" "11339" ...
  ..$ likelihood: num [1:168] 0.998 0.993 0.936 0.966 0.482 ...
 $ 10011    :List of 2
  ..$ tfmode    : Named num [1:88] 1 1 0.999 1 1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:88] "3035" "4695" "113829" "5201" ...
  ..$ likelihood: num [1:88] 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I want to create a 2-column matrix that looks like this:

```
head(newRegul)
      TF   Target
   10001   22938
   10001   5684
   10001   9780
   ...
   10011   3035
   10011   4695
   ...
```

So, there would be 168 rows wherein the first column is "10001" and the second column contains the names of the matching regul$tfmode, followed by 88 rows where column 1 consists of 10011 & column 2 consists of its matching regul$tfmode names, etc.

I've been trying to do this, using unlist() and string splitting, but have been running into a lot of problems. Is there some simple(ish) way to do this?

Thanks and sorry if this is a duplicate question. If it is, please post the link & I'll delete this post.

Comment: or rbindlist from the data.table package with the option idcol=TRUE

Comment: That's a cool function - didn't know about that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `melt` from `library(reshape2)`

```
library(reshape2)
melt(lapply(regul, function(x) names(x[[1]])))
#  value    L1
#1 22938 10001
#2  5564 10001
#3  1123 10011
#4  1533 10011
```

---

Or we can use `stack` in combination with `transpose` from `library(purrr)`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
transpose(regul) %>%
       .$tfmode %>%
        map(names) %>%
        stack
#  values   ind
#1  22938 10001
#2   5564 10001
#3   1123 10011
#4   1533 10011
```

#### data

```
 regul <- list(`10001`=list(tfmode= setNames(c(0.994, 
   0.992), c(22938, 5564)), likelihood=c(0.998, 0.834)),
 `10011`=list(tfmode=setNames(c(0.7, 0.3), c(1123, 
  1533)), likelihood= c(0.4, 0.3)))
```

Comment: That's fantastic - exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much! I had a feeling that the solution would be something simple, that I just wasn't seeing. :-)